# Embedded Links in BridgeIt Augmented Reality component

Tags: html, mobile-website, augmented-reality

How can I embed links to URLs in the custom images when using BridgeIt augmented reality?

Ultimately I want to be able to touch the augmented reality image on the device screen and have it launch the browser to a custom wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

BridgeIt Augmented Reality provides a callback that identifies the selected element.  Once you receive that callback, you can use document.location to launch the wiki page.

Take a look at the onReturnFromAugmentedReality in demo-jqm/augmented-reality.html.

Here the selected element is used to display an icon, but it could easily be converted into a URL.

```
    function onReturnFromAugmentedReality(event)  {
    var selection = event.value;
    if (!!selection)  {
        console.log("AR selected " + selection);
        document.getElementById("selected")
                .setAttribute("src",
                locations[selection].split(",")[4]);
   } else if (event.response)  {
        var len = "Aug".length;
        var responseLoc = "" + JSON.parse(event.response)["_loc"][0];
        console.log("AR selected " + responseLoc);
        document.getElementById("selected")
                .setAttribute("src",
                locations[responseLoc].split(",")[4]);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/bridgeit/demo-jqm